# How to map Alt key?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I'm trying to map <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in the following way:

```
:map <A-j> j
:map <A-k> k
```

but it doesn't work (bell is rang on <kbd>Alt + j</kbd>/<kbd>Alt + k</kbd>).

What am I missing?

I'm using Terminal on OSX, the same happens on remote Linux.

---

On <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd>, <kbd>Alt + j</kbd>, I've got: `?~H~F` (`∆` when `encoding=utf-8`).

On <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd>, <kbd>Alt + k</kbd>, I've got: `?~Z` (`˚` when `encoding=utf-8`).

Running vim without plugins (`-u NONE`) doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Does `Alt` (press, not hold) and then `j` work? With `xterm` at least I need to set `metaSendsEscape` to `true`  to get these sequences to work... I don't know if you have the same problem, and I don't use OSX so I can't test...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Pressing `Alt`, release, then `j` or any other key works as normal. I've checked and found the option ['Use option as meta key'](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54784/22781), enabled it and it works now. So setting `metaSendsEscape` did the trick, thanks.

Comment: This question was previously answered (with a better response) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim/10216459#10216459

Comment: Your `Alt-j` and `Alt-k` was intercepted by your operating system or your Terminal emulator or both. The intercepted action (Find?) as defined in `your_os->system->settings->keybindings` or `your_terminal->settings->keymaps` will tell you where the keystroke sunk.  Delete all entries and vim once again receives your keystroke.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

That's how I do it on Linux or Cygwin:

First check what chars are sent by your terminal when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>:

In order to do this I go to console and run `sed -n l` (you can also use `cat` for it). Then I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and see that the chars on the screen are `^[j` .

I replace `^[` with `\e` (because that's what is sent by my terminal when I press <kbd>esc</kbd>) and the final string for me is `\ej`.

Then I write it to my `.vimrc`:

```
execute "set <M-j>=\ej"
nnoremap <M-j> j
```

And the mapping works.

Comment: I can't find the documentation for the `:set <M-j>=\ej` part. What should I search for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was the only solution that has worked for me w/ Iterm + vim

Comment: Nah, this doesn't work. Sometimes ESC-J will act as ALT-J

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev See `:help :set-termcap`

Comment: I like your "check what chars are sent by your terminal" part. Smart!

Comment: @Kossak I'm on Manjaro Linux, and when I have my terminal open, and press `Alt`+`T`, I just get a [terminal menu opening up](https://imgur.com/a/yb0dbmZ).

Comment: @J86 disable the shortcut in terminal (eg: in Edit => Preferences => Advanced) or hide the menu (View => untick "Show menubar")

Comment: Even though my terminal uses `^[` instead of `\e`, the above mapping works as long as I run the command using `execute`.

Comment: tmux, I had to exit and `tmux kill-server` (reloading config wasn't enough)

Comment: This is a great answer. I am tempted to improve it even further by removing the sed -n -l and just focus on cat.

Answer (score 21):

With help of [Carpetsmoker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key#comment2107_2350), it seems that Terminal wasn't configured to 'Use Alt/option as meta key' (this is especially common for GUI Terminals).

For Terminal on OSX, it's in *Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard tab -> 'Use option as meta key'*. Check: [How can I change Terminal to use option as meta key?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54777/how-can-i-change-terminal-so-that-i-dont-have-to-press-esc-every-time-i-want-to) ([Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146485/can-you-enable-the-meta-key-in-mavericks)).

For XTerm, check: [Configuring XTerm to Default to Meta Sends Escape](http://frequal.com/linux/XTermMetaSendsEscape.html) which says:

> Add this line anywhere in your personal .Xdefaults file (`~/.Xdefaults`):
>
> ```
> xterm*metaSendsEscape: true
> ```
>
> Then reload the config with xrdb. Without this step the changes in `.Xdefaults` won't take effect until the next X restart:
>
> ```
> xrdb -l ~/.Xdefaults
> ```

Then standard mappings with <kbd>Alt</kbd> key like:

```
:map <A-j> j
:map <A-k> k
```

works fine.

For help, see: [`:h :map-alt-keys`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-alt-keys).

Comment: May also want to look at `:h :map-alt-keys` as another source of information

Answer (score 14):

Similar to Kossak's answer but a bit simpler, by mapping literal key presses.

Either in normal mode after pressing <kbd>:</kbd>, or inserted into your `.vimrc`, map the input directly by starting the mapping:

```
nnoremap
```

then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> then the keystroke to record, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>. This will show as something like this:

```
nnoremap ^[[1;3D
```

but each `^[` is a single, literal escape character and syntax highlighting should show this. Replace the literal escape(s) with the text `<Esc>`, and append the command you wish to use:

```
nnoremap <Esc>[1;3D <C-w>h
```

---

I know OP was mapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> + letters, but I used arrows to show how do it for something that may not be mapped by default.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know exactly what vim was interpreting my desired key combo as, and this shows you. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work with my Danish layout.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen What, exactly "doesn't work"? This should be layout independent because you're mapping raw keypresses regardless of what they are. If you can't send [`SYN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-V) on a Danish keyboard, then first figure that out.

Answer (score 4):

If `Control+V` followed by `ALT-x` shows `^[x` (type in terminal) you can fix it with this small script from [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_meta-keys_that_break_out_of_Insert_mode):

```
for i in range(97,122)
  let c = nr2char(i)
  exec "map \e".c." <M-".c.">"
  exec "map! \e".c." <M-".c.">"
endfor
```

Add to .vimrc for all alt key mappings.

Comment: Generally this is a bad idea, as then the <esc> key itself will be delayed.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 xfce terminal (and alacritty rust terminal)

Set ultisnip snippet trigger to `Meta-/` (just like emacs snippet)

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="^[/"
```

Here's now I type `^[/` in vim

In insert mode `Ctrl-V Alt-/`

(`Meta` is the `Alt` key on my PC keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using Terminal on OSX, the same happens on remote Linux.

I don't know about Terminal, but if you are on OSX, your mappings should work out of the box, provided that you use a recent Vim version, and a recent iTerm2 terminal.

You need at least the Vim patch [8.1.2134](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2134).  Having the patch [8.1.2194](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2194) also helps, because it automatically enables the modifyOtherKeys feature on which Vim relies to let the user map various chords.

For iterm2, I think you need at least the version 3.4.0.  From the [changelog](https://iterm2.com/downloads.html):

> - Modifier keys in vim should work better now. CSI
>   u mode is no longer enabled by a control
>   sequence. Instead, a "modifyOtherKeys" mode has
>   been added which is compatible with xterm.

---

On Linux, xterm also supports the modifyOtherKeys feature.

---

You are not limited to meta chords.  You can map many other chords, like `<C-;>` for example:

```
vim -Nu NONE +'nno <c-;> :echo "c-; was hit"<cr>'
```

---

For more info, see [`:h modifyOtherKeys`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#modifyOtherKeys).

Comment: I'm on 8.2.2300, and I couldn't make `nnoremap <A-j> :echo "alt-j"<CR>` work on macOS on either Terminal.app or Alacritty :( oh well, I don't tend to use those chords anyway

Answer (score 1):

You have another option. NeoVim works with `M-x` out of the box when you have terminal sending `ESC` + sequence, which mostly every terminal could.

As a summary for other answers, I think your two options are

1. Turning using "opt as meta" off, using the actual sent code in mapping
2. Turning using "opt as meta" on, using `<esc>x` type of sequence for mapping.

There are some answers stating that just turning on opt as meta would make `<A-x>`/`<M-x>` work. *That is not true*. At least, it will not work on macOS.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've edited your post for some formatting, and also edited out the opinion-based parts to focus on the core facts.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the solutions in this thread to work on macOS because it has special characters mapped to `<alt><letter>`.

I ended up just mapping to the special characters. So `<A-J><M-J>` gets mapped to `å`. It doesn't work in insert mode because the special character will still get inserted, but I spend more time in normal mode anyway.

It's been the simplest working solution for me thus far.