# Why typing `alt + 3` exits insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

In the last week my vim has started to exit insert mode when I type <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

I have changed my theme to tomorrow night, but other than that no updates or changes to `.vimrc`.

Any ideas what could be causing this? I wouldn't have thought a colorscheme could do this.

Comment: You probably updated your terminal emulator to send the escape key on Alt. See: [How to map Alt key?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2350/51) and [`:help :map-alt-keys`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap%2dalt%2dkeys)

Comment: You could add your solution to the other question as an answer, if it's different from the existing answers so that people with the same problem are able to find it :-)

Comment: Yea so my issue was slightly different, I needed to update my terminal settings to disable 'Use Option as Meta Key' which had been enabled somehow. I just happened to get to that solution through `:help :map-alt-keys`

Comment: That's exactly the same solution as the OP used in the other question ;-)

Comment: haha, sure is! Saw the top voted comment not the accepted answer. Cheers!