# How to map Alt-PageUp in Vim?

Tags: key-bindings

[I know about this thread.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key)
Using `sed -n l`, I get the following output

for pageUp : `^[[5~`

for alt+pageUp : `^[[5;3~`

The alt+pageUp seems to be sending new char altogether and not combination of Pageup char `^[[5~` and some other char.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it. It was straight forward!

```
:map <A-PageUp> {rhs}
```

Comment: See also ":help keycodes".