# How to map Alt key with M J K L U I O to make a numpad?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I would like to have the keys M, J, K, L, U, I, O to be mapped to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (combine with the keys 7, 8, 9 already being on top of those keys) to be a total numpad when I hold a modifier key, say Alt/Meta.

In that way commands with numbers like 25j, d3w, etc. would be easier and faster to be typed. But I haven't figured out how to make this happen.

As it is said in this answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2363/21584, I've tried this solution:

```
execute "set <M-j>=\ej"
nnoremap <M-j> 1
```

But it only works with commands which begin with a single number (7j), however complex commands which have number inside or multiple number (d3w, 25j) don't work.

I use Ubuntu 18.04, on terminal Kitty.

Comment: @klaus my bad, I mean Ubuntu 18.04. But I think that doesn't really matter.

Comment: copy-paste all the codes in your vimrc regarding this mapping, i.e. not just `<M-j>` but all of `<M-k>` etc. It would be easier for people to copy-paste themselves and as a result more easier to help you.

Comment: Creating mappings for this is potentially very hard—youd have to accept keypresses as long as it’s a « number » and then, when it’s not, feedkeys it all back to vim.

Comment: @klaus, Knoble thanks I've got the solution, please check out my answer it probably could help you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I find out in this guide: https://howchoo.com/g/nzc1ztu4ztd/custom-key-mappings-vim#triggering-our-custom-key-mapping

What I was missing was the Operator-pending Mode, which is the case of the command like d3w.

This is how I modified the mappings (I didn't think it would turn out to be this simple):

```
noremap ^[j 1
noremap ^[k 2
noremap ^[l 3
" etc.
```

Where `^[` is the Escape character, and `map` applies the mapping for Normal, Visual and Operator-pending Mode. Now I can use Alt + J K L... to simulate the numpad on the right hand. Typing commands containing numbers is feeling more and more comfy now.

Hope this could help you guys :)

Comment: Consider using `:h :noremap` version of `:h mapmode-nvo`

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense to use noremap