# How do you represent "/" character in .vim?

Tags: key-bindings, nvim

Trying to map the `NERDCommenter`'s toggle comment action (mapped to `<leader>c<space>`) to `alt+/`, something a bit more familiar. I tried:

`nnoremap <A-/> <leader>c<space>`

...but it doesn't seem to work or do anything. Do I have the key `alt+/` wrong ? how can you represent the `/` character in `.vim` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map Alt key?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key)

Comment: `/` is `/`. It's not the problem. Did you try Insert mode, hit `Ctrl-V` then hit `Alt-/`? Whatever you see there make that the mapped key. In one of my environments it's `^[/`. The `^[` is the control character equivalent to `Esc`. So I do `nnoremap <Esc>/  etc`. That's an example.

Comment: I just noticed you said "nvim" in your comment (but not in your question...you should specify that). See `:h :map-alt-keys`. (It says something similar to my last comment.) ..... (Edit: I added "nvim" tag to your question)

Comment: Just tried it, it just doesn't read anything it seems, like nothing is sent through or vim is listening for the wrong key. Because literally no action takes place, I go to insert mode, press `ctrl-o`, and press `alt+/` but nothing takes places, it just keeps waiting for a command.

I tried:
`nnoremap ^[/ <leader>c<space>`
`nnoremap <Esc>/ <leader>c<space>`
`nnoremap <A-/> <leader>c<space>`

Comment: `Ctrl-V` not `Ctrl-O`

Comment: I ended up configuring my terminal to output `^[*` whenever I press `alt+/` and configured nvim to listen for, the equivalent, `<A-*>`. Now it all works great.

Comment: Glad you got things working to your liking but Alt-/ shouldn't be broken like that. What if you configure the terminal to output `^[/` ? (!) Beyond that problem could be misconfiguration of the terminal or Vim's terminal config. You can try the following to see whether the problem is isolated to Vim: from shell prompt `cat > /tmp/foo`, type `Alt-/` then hit Enter, type `Ctrl-D`, then run `cat -v /tmp/foo`. Similar to the `Ctrl-V` test in Vim this will show you the actual characters emitted by `Alt-/`. See anything different doing it this way?