# Mappings that work in nvim not working in vim

Tags: key-bindings

I have these key mappings that I use a lot in nvim, but they don't work in vim:

```
" Move lines with Alt+Shift+j/k
nnoremap <A-S-j> :m .+1<CR>==                                                                                                                                                               
nnoremap <A-S-k> :m .-2<CR>==                                                                                                                                                               
inoremap <A-S-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi                                                                                                                                                        
inoremap <A-S-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi                                                                                                                                                        
vnoremap <A-S-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-S-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

Instead I get the Join Words and Help  actions as though the `Alt` key wasn't being pressed (in Normal Mode).

I have tried using capital `J` and `K` instead, but that didn't help.

Does vim not accept key bindings with `Alt` and `Shift` together, or is there some option that needs to be enabled or disabled?

---

**MORE INFO:**
I explicitly set as many options as I can for consistency, as I use the same configuration between nvim, vim and gvim and Linux and Windows, but there are so many that I don't have all of them set.

Currently I am using:

- Linux x86_64 I use nvim 0.72 (appimage) and vim 8.2 for git
- Linux aarch64 I am using vim 8.2
- On Windows I am using vim 9.0 and gvim 9.0

These key mappings are only working on nvim.

Comment: Depending on the version of Vim your are using there are key combination that are mapped to the same code. Ctrl-Shift-s and Ctrl-s is a standard example for Vim 7.3. Both Vim and Neovim are working on that. What version of Vim are you using,

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I have added more info above. Thanks.

Comment: I'll check if I can reproduce your problem and let you know :-)

Comment: I have tried successfully to map `<A-a>` and `<A-S-a>` to two different key sequence on Windows 10 with gVim 8.1, 8.2 and 9.0.

Comment: Maybe could you try with a very slim `.vimrc` starting Vim with the `-U NONE -i NONE` options to reduce the impact of previous sessions.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I deleted everything from `.vimrc` apart from those key mappings and the problem remained.

Comment: I also just had the original version from this page in my `.vimrc` with nothing else and it still didn't work. Very strange. https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down#Mappings_to_move_lines

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate. [How to map Alt key?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key) doesn't specifically mention the Shift key, but I don't think that changes anything: the answers are the same. (Although it's very weird this doesn't seem to be working for you in gVim: your original mappings should be fine there).

Comment: @Rich I couldn't find that answer when asking the question. I personally think that keeping it open would help people find the solution if they are have the same query.

Comment: @Rich They are working in gvim as well, using a conditional statement for both variants.

Comment: @paradroid Closing the question doesn’t remove it: it just adds a prominent link to the older question. i.e. It should *help* future readers find the existing answers.

Comment: @paradroid Not 100% sure I’m understanding you right, but you shouldn’t need a conditional statement to get your mappings working in gVim: they should work as is.

Comment: @Rich [In my comments below](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38639/mappings-that-work-in-nvim-not-working-in-vim?noredirect=1#comment70688_38650). I use the same config for both Windows and Linux (git repo), so I needed to use conditional statements to use both ways of setting the mappings so that they work on all versions. I closed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use `Alt` explicitly in your mappings. Instead of that, you need to press `Ctrl+v` in insert mode and then press the desired mapping (e.g. `alt+shif+j`). For your first mapping, it should look as follows:

```
nnoremap ^[J :m .+1<CR>==
```

and that should work.

Comment: Yes. It now works in vim as well as nvim now. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it doesn't  work in vim/gvim for Windows but I can live with that and at least the other behaviour doesn't occur, as that was the main problem due to habit.

Comment: @paradroid I believe it depends on whether you're using terminal vim or gvim. In gvim, you need to use `<A-S-j>`. Not sure if you tested in that way. I don't have a machine with Windows installed, so I cannot verify if there is an additional edge case to take into account.

Comment: Working on all platforms with `if has('unix')`...`elseif has('win32')`. Cheers.

Comment: That's great :)

Comment: I have another related question here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/38848/37532