# How to map key code sequences without delay?

Tags: key-bindings

Neovim doesn't recognize Ctrl+Left or Ctrl+Right for me in urxvt, so for ages I've had the key code sequences urxvt produces mapped like so:

```
map <Esc>Od <C-Left>
map! <Esc>Od <C-Left>
map <Esc>Oc <C-Right>
map! <Esc>Oc <C-Right>
```

But I recently found these were the reason why I have a second long delay after pressing Escape to leave insert mode.
I'd like to be able to use `<C-Left>` and `<C-Right>` but not cause the delay to the Escape key

I saw a comment that said you should do this:

```
set <C-Left>=^[Od
```

(Where ^[ is produced by pressing Ctrl+v then Escape)
But it did nothing, and I tried `setlocal` too.

I looked into turning timeout off for specific mappings but didn't find anything.

What can I do?
(I don't want to change the sequences urxvt produces in my xresources file)

`:echo &term` outputs `rxvt-unicode-256color`

Comment: does this help? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key/29538#29538

Comment: @Mass from quick tests enabling and disabling it, it doesn't seem to help but thank you